# How to change image of a Powerpoint shape?

Tags: excel, vba, powerpoint

This is my PowerPoint file:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/7my3ubmnv7rxv8y/temp.pptx?dl=0

This is my code to change image of shape:

```
Dim presentation As Object
Set ppt = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")    
Set presentation = ppt.Presentations.Open2007("D:\2018\temp.pptx", MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoFalse, MsoTriState.msoTrue)
Dim oSlide As Object            
Set oSlide = presentation.Slides(1)
oSlide.Shapes("Picture").Fill.UserPicture ("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg")
```

How can I change the image of the Shape object?

Comment: How is it not working? Does it give an error? Or just not doing anything?

Comment: it not doing anything. it still display old image.

Comment: Does the shape "Picture" exist?

Comment: Yes. i set name of shape.

Comment: You can't use Fill to change a picture. See the answer below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are trying to do is to create a fill, which doesn't work because the shape in question is a picture. You can try it out yourself in PowerPoint. Setting a fill to a picture has no effect because the original image is still visible. That's why you see no result.
You can't change the picture itself, you have to delete it, and then replace. So you can amend the necessary section of your code as follows:

```vb
Set shp = oSlide.Shapes("Picture")
'Capture properties of the existing picture such as location and size
With shp
    t = .Top
    l = .Left
    h = .Height
    w = .Width
End With

shp.Delete 'Delete old shape

Set shp = oSlide.Shapes.AddPicture("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg", msoFalse, msoTrue, l, t, w, h)

shp.Name = "Picture"
shp.ScaleHeight Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
shp.ScaleWidth Factor:=1, RelativeToOriginalSize:=msoTrue
```

Of course, you can make your initial shape a *rectangle* (or other drawing objects) and then **Fill** it with a picture. In this case, you can always change the **Fill** and the picture used for it, something like this:

```vb
Dim link as String 'set this to the address of the picture you want to use to fill
oSlide.Shapes(shp).Fill.UserPicture(link)
```

**But if the original shape is a Picture itself, you usually can't fill it with another picture.**

Comment: i try this code: it can change:Dim newShape As Object
        Set newShape = oSlide.Shapes.AddShape(MsoAutoShapeType.msoShapeRectangle, 0, 0, 100, 50)
        newShape.Fill.UserPicture ("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Penguins.jpg")
        newShape.Fill.UserPicture ("C:\Users\Public\Pictures\Sample Pictures\Chrysanthemum.jpg"). What is difference between oSlide.Shapes("Picture") and newShape?

Comment: In this case, your original shape is no longer a picture. It's a rectangle which is filled with a picture. You can change the fill at any time in that case, but not if the original shape was a picture. I can update the answer to reflect this.

Comment: If you're working with picture-filled shapes, you also want to be sure that the shape's aspect ratio matches the new fill picture's aspect ratio; otherwise, the picture will be distorted. On the plus side, if you change the picture by using picture-filled shapes, any animation applied to the original shape will be preserved.